# 4 table query / join. getting duplicate rows

Tags: sql, mysql, join

So I have written a query that will grab an order (this is for an ecommerce type site), and from that order id it will get all order items (ecom_order_items), print options (c_print_options) and images (images). The eoi_p_id is currently a foreign key from the images table.

This works fine and the query is:

```
SELECT
eoi_parentid, eoi_p_id, eoi_po_id, eoi_quantity,
i_id, i_parentid,
po_name, po_price
FROM ecom_order_items, images, c_print_options WHERE eoi_parentid = '1' AND i_id = eoi_p_id AND po_id = eoi_po_id;
```

The above would grab all the stuff I need for order #1

Now to complicate things I added an extra table (ecom_products), which needs to act in a similar way to the images table. The eoi_p_id can also point at a foreign key in this table too. I have added an extra field 'eoi_type' which will either have the value 'image', or 'product'.

Now items in the order could be made up of a mix of items from images or ecom_products. Whatever I try it either ends up with too many records, wont actually output any with eoi_type = 'product', and just generally wont work. Any ideas on how to achieve what I am after? Can provide SQL samples if needed?

```
SELECT
eoi_id, eoi_parentid, eoi_p_id, eoi_po_id, eoi_po_id_2, eoi_quantity, eoi_type,
i_id, i_parentid,
po_name, po_price, po_id,
ep_id
FROM ecom_order_items, images, c_print_options, ecom_products WHERE eoi_parentid = '9' AND i_id = eoi_p_id AND po_id = eoi_po_id
```

The above outputs duplicate rows and doesnt work as expected. Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I have seperate foreign key fields for the eoi_p_id depending it its an image or a product?

Should I be using JOINs?

Here is a mysql explain of the tables in question

```
ecom_products

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ep_id       | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ep_title    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ep_link     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ep_desc     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ep_imgdrop  | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ep_price    | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ep_category | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ep_hide     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| ep_featured | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

ecom_order_items

+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| eoi_id       | int(8)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| eoi_parentid | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eoi_type     | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eoi_p_id     | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eoi_po_id    | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eoi_quantity | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

c_print_options

+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| po_id      | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| po_name    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| po_price   | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

images

+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| i_id         | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| i_filename   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| i_data       | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| i_parentid   | int(8)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd write the first query. I prefer to use joins.

```
SELECT eoi_parentid, eoi_p_id, eoi_po_id, eoi_quantity, i_id, i_parentid, po_name, po_price
FROM ecom_order_items
INNER JOIN images
    ON i_id = eoi_p_id
INNER JOIN c_print_options 
    ON po_id = eoi_po_id
WHERE eoi_parentid = '1'
```

For your second query I would use a UNION on two queries, one for images and one for products.

```
SELECT eoi_id, eoi_parentid, eoi_p_id, eoi_po_id, eoi_po_id_2, eoi_quantity, eoi_type, i_id, i_parentid, po_name, po_price, po_id, ep_id
FROM ecom_order_items
INNER JOIN images
    ON i_id = eoi_p_id
INNER JOIN c_print_options
    ON po_id = eoi_po_id
WHERE eoi_type = 'image' AND i_id = eoi_p_id --Image conditions
  AND eoi_parentid = '9'   
  AND po_id = eoi_po_id

UNION

SELECT eoi_id, eoi_parentid, eoi_p_id, eoi_po_id, eoi_po_id_2, eoi_quantity, eoi_type, i_id, i_parentid, po_name, po_price, po_id, ep_id
FROM ecom_order_items
INNER JOIN images
    ON i_id = eoi_p_id
INNER JOIN c_print_options
    ON po_id = eoi_po_id
WHERE eoi_type = 'product' AND ep_id = eoi_p_id -- Product conditions
  AND eoi_parentid = '9' 
  AND po_id = eoi_po_id
```

Comment: This sort of works, however the bottom part of the union returns 0 rows. This is because if its a product, it doesnt have any print options, and removing it from the bottom query has ramifications on the top one eg, selected columns need to match up

Comment: Yay! with a bit of tinkering I got it working, needed a left join on the print options bit in the second query. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. I was just sitting on the couch and realized that the columns in the select list might not match up properly, glad you caught that. Although, on another note, you asked "Should I have seperate foreign key fields" and after giving it some thought I think yes you should. Images and products don't seem to have anything in common. Why complicate the relationship with a type field when you could just have two FKs?

Comment: I did it mainly because there could in the future be more than 2

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a join condition for ecom_products either in the WHERE or FROM Clause. This is how it would be done using ANSI-92 joins

```
SELECT
   eoi_id, 
   eoi_parentid, 
   eoi_p_id, 
   eoi_po_id, 
   eoi_po_id_2, 
   eoi_quantity, 
   eoi_type,
   i_id, 
   i_parentid,
   po_name, 
   po_price, 
   po_id,
   ep_id
FROM 
   ecom_order_items, 
   LEFT JOIN images
   ON i_id = eoi_p_id  
   LEFT JOIN c_print_options
   ON po_id = eoi_po_id 
   INNER JOIN ecom_products 
   ON eoi_p_id = ep_id
WHERE
   eoi_parentid = '9'
```

ANSI 92 joins are preferred and its a little clearer what's a join and what's filtering. That said you could just add `AND eoi_p_id = ep_id` to you where clause.

Comment: There is the additional problem of the dual purpose foreign key. You need to take this into consideration in your ON clause(s), or use a UNION as I have.

Comment: This returns 0 rows, which i suspect is due to the same reason as the below post by whatispunk. Need to make the print options potentially have no results, so a left join maybe?

Comment: If there's a potential for no print options just make it a left join A UNION is overkill

Comment: What Conrad is saying is another possibility. You could have a LEFT JOIN for both images and products. You could condense my above UNION query into one by turning the JOIN of images and products into LEFT JOINs.